# Getting a closed interval subset for user defined classes in Java

Tags: java, collections, set, range

> As per Java API :
>
> The following one-liner tells you how many words between "doorbell"
>   and "pickle", including doorbell and pickle, are contained in the
>   dictionary.
>
> count = dictionary.subSet("doorbell", "pickle\0").size();

I understand that for a set of String elements, appending "\0" would work and for a set of Integer elements, using +1 would work.

If the set contains user defined objects, the subset() gives a half open range.

```
count = employee.subSet(obj1, obj6).size();
```

I was wondering if there is any possible way to get a closed range in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `NavigableSet` (e.g. a `TreeSet`), you could simply use the [`subSet` overload which takes inclusivity parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet-E-boolean-E-boolean-):

```
employee.subSet(obj1, true, obj6, true)
```

For a general `SortedSet`, the only ways you could do this are:

1. Define some notion of constructing the `Employee` which is "just beyond" the upper bound.

   You could do this by knowing something of the internals of the class, e.g. if `Employee`s are sorted by surname and your upper bound's surname were `"Turner"`, you could construct an employee called `"Turner\0"`.
2. Do it "manually" by iterating the set:

   ```
   SortedSet<Employee> subset = employees.tailSet(obj1);
   for (Employee employee : subset) {
     if (employee.compareTo(obj6) < 0) {
       subset = subset.headSet(obj6);
       break;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.